# knockout conditional animations depending on parent list length

Tags: knockout.js

I have a performance issue using animations with knockout. 
Here is my code :

```
<ul data-bind="template: {foreach: items, beforeRemove: slideup }">
  <li data-bind="text: text"></li>
</ul>
<script>
  var slideup = function (elem) {
     if (elem.nodeType === 1) $(elem).slideUp(100, function () {$(this).remove();});
  }
</script>
```

Problem occurs when I do removeAll on a list with hundreds elements. In this case I'd rather fire a hardcut. 
Do you know if I can have access to the length of the list in the slideUp function, or if can conditionally bind the animation?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [this documentation page](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html). It looks like you may be able to do what you want using a custom `update` function.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var slideup = function (elem) {
    var context = ko.contextFor(elem);
    if (elem.nodeType === 1) {
        if (context.$parent.length < 100) {
            $(elem).slideUp(100, function () {$(this).remove();});
        }
        else {
            $(elem).remove();
        }
    }
}
```